# quartz spring design suggestion

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

i have few jobs that runs using quartz + spring in clustered environment. these jobs are not setup to run in clustered environment so each job will run multiple times based on number of instances we have. these jobs run on AWS environment. so we are not sure how many instances would be running as we can increase or decrease dynamically. so we are in process of refactoring the code.

problem, lets take example of job which send emails to users based on certain activity. there might be daily 1000 users where we need to send email.

currently as this is not setup to run in clustered environment each instance runs the job and send email to users about their activity. so if i have 3 instances running, job will be run 3 times and same email is send to user 3 times.

we decided to use quartz jdbc to make sure job runs only 1 time.

i am looking for suggestion on how to do below part.

lets says i have to send email to 300 users, rather than job running on 1 instance picking the users and sending the email to 300 users, i want job on any instance to get 300 users from DB and later same job on other instances also take part in processing those 300 users. what would be best way to do it. i don't want to store those 300 users in temp table and job picking users from DB. is there a way i can store those 300 users in global memory like memcached and job on different instance picking data from there (kind of load balancing while processing the users). i don't want to use memcache, so any other options available or best way i can go ahead with design.

Comment: is it your application which is inserting records in DB ? or your application only picking the records from the DB and sending emails ?

Comment: this application will get the list of users using rest services and for each user calls other rest service to send email

Answer (score 0):

a few months ago we have the same problem. We fix this creating a table called job as you can see below, only to control what scheduler is running.

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| createdAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| version   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| running   | tinyint(4)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| scheduler | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Basically the first instance when start the scheduler set 'running' attribute to 1(running) and when finish set to 0(stop).

Problems with this approach:

- Every scheduler has the same bunch of code to verify the table (redundant code).
- If you forget this bunch, the scheduler doesn't work correctly.

Not the best solution but with palliative it works.

Comment: Thanks for response, but this really doesn't help me as we are planning to use quartz jdbc support but my question is mainly on how to do load balancing while processing the list of users i got from my first job.